# How do I make a cURL request to zomato api?

Tags: json, python-2.7, zomato-api

I just began exploring APIs. This is my code so far. For locu API this works but for Zomato they use curl header request which I don't know how to use. Could someone guide or show me how?

```
import json
import urllib2

Key = 'Zomato_key'

url = 'https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/categories'

json_obj = urllib2.urlopen(url)

data = json.load(json_obj)

print data
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By looking at the [Zomato API docs](https://developers.zomato.com/documentation#!/common/categories), it seems that the parameter `user-key` has to be set in the header.

The following works:

```
import json
import urllib2

Key = '<YOUR_ZOMATO_API_KEY>'
url = "https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/categories"

request = urllib2.Request(url, headers={"user-key" : Key})
json_obj = urllib2.urlopen(request)
data = json.load(json_obj)

print data
```

If you want a more elegant way to query APIs, have a look at `requests` module (you can install using `pip install requests`).

I suggest you the following:

```
import json
import requests

Key = <YOUR_ZOMATO_API_KEY>'
url = "https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/categories"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    r = requests.get(url, headers={'user-key': Key})
    if r.ok:
        data = r.json()
        print data
```

NB: I suggest you remove your Key from StackOverflow if you care about keeping it to yourself.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have been looking for resources to learn this. Just wondering could you point me any material online that teaches API requests.

Comment: You can start with the [requests documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/). Please accept the answer if you think this resolved your question.

Answer (score 0):

this didn't work for me can u suggest some other method for me.
-->the code when tried to compile is taking long time and returning an traceback error in request method that is in built

but curl command is working
curl -X GET --header "Accept: application/json" --header "user-key: c5062d18e16b9bb9d857391bb32bb52f" "https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/categories"

Comment: Hi, the question was to do it with code, not the curl command.  This answer would be better as a comment to the question.